# Set numpy matrix elements to zero if varying row index is exceeded

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I have a quite large `m` times `n` numpy matrix `M` filled with non-zero values and an array `x` of length m, where each entry indicates the row index, after which the matrix elements should be set to zero. So for example, if `n=5` and `x[i]=3`, then the i-th row of the matrix be set to `[M_i1, M_i2, M_i3, 0, 0]`.

If all entries of `x` had the same value `k`, I could simply use slicing with something like `M[:,k:]=0`, but I could not figure out an efficient way to this with different values for each row without looping over all rows and use slicing for each row.

I thougt about creating a matrix that looks like `[[1]*x[1] + [0]*(n-x[1]),...,[1]*x[m] + [0]*(n-x[m])]` and use it for boolean indexing but also don't know how to create this without looping.

The non-vectorized solution looks like this:

```
for i in range(m):
    if x[i] < n:
        M[i,x[i]:] = 0
```

with example input

```
M = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
m, n =  2, 3
x = np.array([1,2])
```

and output

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 0]])
```

Does anyone have a vectorized solution for this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, post the non-vectorized solution ?

Comment: @ce.teuf added it

Comment: Please post sample input and output

Comment: So some `x` may be too large?  And nothing is supposed to happen for those rows?

Comment: @hpaulj the maximal value of x is n, so it can only happen that it's too large by a value of 1.

Comment: In the loop solution you don't need the `if` test, since `M[i,n:]=0` still works.  That is, it's ok to slice off the end (for arrays and lists).

Comment: @hpaulj Ah yes you are right, thank you. But that's still not solving the problem

Comment: @Leguan3000 Maybe you can find a "vectorized" solution. But a vectorized solution doesn't guarantee a better running time for your problem. In terms of cache efficiency, your non-vectorized is already at its best since you don't have to deal with the elements before `x[i]`. In contrast, a fully vectorized solution (maybe with mask) will have to generate a large intermediate boolean matrix and have to load all elements in both matrices into cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multi-dimensional boolean indexing:

```
M[x[:,None]<=np.arange(M.shape[1])] = 0
```

example:

```
M = [[7, 8, 4, 2, 3, 9, 1, 8, 4, 3],
     [2, 1, 6, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 9, 2],
     [6, 1, 6, 8, 4, 3, 6, 9, 2, 6],
     [5, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 8, 7],
     [8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 2, 0, 8, 0, 2]]
x = [4, 4, 0, 6, 2]
```

output:

```
      [[7, 8, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Set one of the elements of `x` to 10 or more. Does it still work?

Comment: I've tried this approach. It is indeed vectorized but way slower than the "non-vectorized" method using a for loop. The problem is it implicitly generates a m by n boolean matrix, which is very inefficient.

Comment: @ShihaoXu. That's not very inefficient if you do it right. What did the timing look like? I'm getting that this is 1.5x faster even for a trivial array, and only gets better from there

Comment: @MadPhysicist I assumed the indexes are in bound, but even if it is greater than bound, it should work.  Should it not?

Comment: @ShihaoXu I would be surprised if it is slower than loop. Specially for large enough arrays. What method do you use to time it?

Comment: @Ehsan Basically we have the same idea. But I've just used your code for testing and it shows about the same results as mine. The non-vectorized solution with a for loop costs 5ms and the vectorized solution costs 16ms. I'm using jupyter notebook and `%timeit`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've tried using a 4000x3000 matrix. The vectorized solution is 3x slower than the original.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Appreciate the effort. I like the `cumsum` idea too. In fact, your answers are great in general.

Comment: @ShihaoXu. Strangely enough, I can reproduce your result. I get a 4x speedup for the non-vectorized solution as well

Comment: @Ehsan. Unfortunately, my version is 20-30% slower than yours.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the confirmation. Actually it is not that strange. The original code has something like `M[i,x[i]:] = 0`, which indicates that the CPU won't have load the values before `x[i]` for that line (hence the matrix could be loaded as a "sparse" matrix, the running time is stochastic, depending on the vector `x`). However with a boolean indexing matrix, the matrix is not as "sparse". And the running time is deterministic, not depending on the value of `x` anymore.

Comment: @ShihaoXu, I expect there's a middle range where this vectorized solution is fastest.  For small examples, Python loops often are faster, especially if they use lists instead of arrays.  And for very large problems, memory management complexity reduces the efficiency of vectorized solutions.

Comment: @ShihaoXu interesting. In that case, maybe you can use `np.r_`, but I doubt it will speed up anything.

Comment: @hpaulj. For the toy matrix in this example, the advantage is ~1.5x. For a 3000x4000 matrix, it goes up to ~3-4x. Doesn't look like there's a crossover point at all

Comment: @hpaulj You're right. I think it up to Leguan3000 to decide which is more important - efficiency or aesthetics :)

Comment: @ShihaoXu, I was wrong.  Even for a (3000,4000) M, the loop was still 2x+ faster.  The sliced assignment must giving it the advantage.

Comment: @hpaulj I've observed huge running time improvement for broadcasting operations and other elementwise independent operations. In such a non-trivial case, I think the hardware plays an important role. Maybe it's another story if someone try to implement it on a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mask-smearing exercise. At each row, you want to smear starting with the element at `np.minimum(x[row], n)`:

```
mask = np.zeros(M.shape, bool)
mask[np.flatnonzero(x < n), x[x < n]] = True
M[np.cumsum(mask, axis=1, dtype=bool)] = 0
```